# Why do I keep getting a type error: This COM object can not automate the makepy process - please run makepy manually for this object with excel?

Tags: python, pywin32

Before I ran the code and it worked, now when I changed nothing it throws me an error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\gencache.py", line 530, in EnsureDispatch
>       ti = disp.*oleobj*.GetTypeInfo()
>   pywintypes.com_error: (-2147418111, 'Call was rejected by callee.', None, None)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/matth/Desktop/dad_app/test.py", line 5, in 
    excel = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
  File "C:\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\gencache.py", line 541, in EnsureDispatch
    raise TypeError("This COM object can not automate the makepy process - please run makepy manually for this object")
TypeError: This COM object can not automate the makepy process - please run makepy manually for this object

```
import win32com.client as win32
import time
import sys
import pyautogui
pyautogui.alert("sdf")
stock = sys.argv[1]
excel = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
wb = excel.Workbooks.Open('C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\dad_app\\template\\template.xlsm')
ws = wb.Worksheets('Overview')
ws.Range("E8").Value = stock
time.sleep(10)
wb.SaveAs('C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\dad_app\\data\\' + stock + '.xlsm')
excel.Application.Quit()
pyautogui.alert(stock)
```

Comment: im stuck on same issue :c

Comment: Was this resolved? I am facing the same issue now.